# Passing SQL Query through OPEN MYSQL port?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, url

Let's assume I have opened port 3306 for external MYSQL Database access.

How can I send a query like this as an parameter in the URL-

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
```

So as it looks something like this- `xx.xx.xxx.xxx:3306?query=SELECT * FROM TableName`

Any external dependency I need to setup on my machine to perform this task?

Comment: What do you want? It's not a very good idea to send the query in the URL.

Comment: This isn't going to work, your expecting port 3306 to act as a HTTP endpoint.  It has it's own protocol and needs a lot more processing than a simple request can provide.  Use something like REST in a web app to do this.

Comment: MySQL and tsql? At least one of those tags should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access MySQL using HTTP/S protocol unless you enable some kind of plugin like HTTP Plugin (experimental).

But you can have a look at using a REST interface in front of your database like the one suggested in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771485/exposing-mysql-database-table-using-rest)